# Adding anchors to a URL in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, devise, routes

I'm needing to refresh the page when a user's update fails. The problem I'm finding is that I don't know how to add a fragment to the url when the page refreshes. The code below is from my Registrations controller, based off of the Devise gem.

```
  def update
    self.resource = resource_class.to_adapter.get!(send(:"current_#{resource_name}").to_key)
    prev_unconfirmed_email = resource.unconfirmed_email if resource.respond_to?(:unconfirmed_email)

    if resource.update_with_password(account_update_params)
      # If the update went well
      if is_navigational_format?
        flash_key = update_needs_confirmation?(resource, prev_unconfirmed_email) ?
          :update_needs_confirmation : :updated
        set_flash_message :notice, flash_key
      end

      sign_in resource_name, resource, :bypass => true
      # What's crazy is this works
      respond_with resource, location: edit_user_registration_path(anchor: params["tab_selected"])
    else
      # If the update goes horribly wrong
      clean_up_passwords resource
      #  this is where the problem occurs below
      respond_with resource, location: edit_user_registration_path(anchor: params["tab_selected"])
    end
  end
```

As you can see, I thought adding the location option would fix this but my url still returns as `coolsite.com/users` when it should return as `coolsite.com/users/#profile`. My question is how do I set the fragment to the URL?

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is because you're using `respond_with`. If the update does succeed, then `respond_with` will issue a `redirect_to` which will use your `:location` option.

However if the update doesn't succeed, `respond_with` just calls `render` on the `edit` template, which basically ignores the `:location` option. It doesn't matter what path you put in there, it won't show up in the address bar of the browser - you've already issued a request to whatever URL maps to the `update` action, all it's doing is supplying the response. In this case the `location` header still gets set in the response, but essentially does nothing because you're responding with a 200 status code, not issuing a redirect (e.g. a 302 or whatever like `redirect_to` does).

In order to have your anchor, you need the browser to issue a second request (or use some sort of JS hackery), i.e. you need to issue a redirect response like in the first case. I think for that to happen you won't be able to use `respond_with`. It may also cause issues with displaying validation errors and remembering any previous values you entered into the form (which may or may not be an issue in your case).

This is the main problem with `respond_with`, it obscures what the controller is doing quite a lot, so you need a good understanding of how it works. [It's being removed from Rails 4.2 and put into a gem](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/16526) anyway, so my advice would be to start using `respond_to` and/or basic render/redirect calls instead.